# When I toggle light/dark modes, by background always stays black

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS in a NextJS app and I have `darkMode: "class"` configured there.

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

//should be light grey when in light mode
:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 43, 43, 43;
    --background-end-rgb: 58, 58, 58;
  }
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}

@layer utilities {
  .text-balance {
    text-wrap: balance;
  }
}
```

I'm also using a custom  to wrap my  in _app.tsx:

```
const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: IThemeProviderProps) => {
  const themeMode = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.theme.mode);

  return (
    <MUIThemeProvider theme={themeMode === "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
      {children}
    </MUIThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

My _app.tsx

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <CustomThemeProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </CustomThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Is it possible I'm overwriting the CSS rules for the background color elsewhere? Do I need to provide a theme.ts file with light/dark themes if I'm using the built in tailwindCSS functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[next-theme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-themes)** package :

first install it : **yarn add next-themes**

then add **ThemeProvider**:

```html
//_app.js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider attribute="class">
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

also you can use this button for change theme mode any where:

```html
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";


const ToggleThemeButton = () => {
    const { systemTheme, theme, setTheme } = useTheme();
    const currentTheme = theme === 'system' ? systemTheme : theme;

    return (
        <button
            onClick={() => theme == "dark"? setTheme('light'): setTheme("dark")}
            className='bg-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-300 transition-all duration-100 text-white dark:text-gray-800 px-8 py-2 text-2xl md:text-4xl rounded-lg absolute bottom-32'>
            Toggle Mode
        </button>
    )
}

export default ToggleThemeButton
```

now use can use like this in your elements's className or css files:

```html
//global.css
:root {
  /* Your default theme */
  --background: white;
  --foreground: black;
}

[data-theme='dark'] {
  --background: black;
  --foreground: white;
}
@layer base{
    background-color: var(--background);
    color:var(--foreground)
}

//in elements
<div className="bg-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-50">...</div>
```